# UITebleView self.editButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView that works properly with the "self.editButtonItem".
The problem that I am chasing is the following:

If I put the table in edit mode, switch to another screen of my app and then go back to the table, I can set the table to DON'T be anymore in edit mode, but the button persist in the "edit" state while I would like it to show me agin the "Edit" label (so, to be consistent with the table state, let's say).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at this recently but I believe you need to set the navigation controller editing to NO, not the tableview. And If you set the nav controller to editing NO, it will set the table view editing to NO as well. 
Hope that helps.